# LCOV to exclude entire packages from code coverage analysis

Tags: html, c++, regex, gcov, lcov

I'm using LCOV as my graphical means of code coverage to tell me how much of my code I've tested, however it's including folders of code which I do not care about and it's making my coverage lower than it should actually be.

Is there a way exclude entire directories where I can ignore a bunch of cpp files which I don't care about? I know about `--remove` but this doesn't seem to work for this purpose. I want to exclude all folders following this pattern:

*Src/GeneralSubSystems/GA/* except for Iterators

Here is the directories I want to ignore

```
**Src/GeneralSubSystems/GA/Iterators**  I want to include this but exclude everything else
Src/GeneralSubSystems/GA/Converters 
Src/GeneralSubSystems/GA/Utils  
Src/GeneralSubSystems/GA/Models 
Src/GeneralSubSystems/GA/Collapse   
Src/GeneralSubSystems/GA/Interview  
Src/GeneralSubSystems/GA/Misc1  
Src/GeneralSubSystems/GA/Misc2
Src/GeneralSubSystems/GA/Misc3
Src/GeneralSubSystems/GA/Misc4
Src/GeneralSubSystems/GA/Misc5
```

Here is my current usage:

```
lcov --gcov-tool /usr/bin/gcov --capture --no-checksum --directory /jenkins/workspace/TCONVENGINE-INSTRUMENTED-BUILD/TCONV/Main/targs/Src --directory /jenkins/workspace/TCONVENGINE-INSTRUMENTED-BUILD/TCONV/Main/targs/Component --output-file ${WORKSPACE}/tps_coverage.info

lcov --remove ${WORKSPACE}/tconv_coverage.info '*/ThrdPrty/*' '*/Src/Low/*' '*/Src/TCCP-C/*' '*/Src/Tool/*' '*/zinAttInterviewDisassembler.*' '/usr/*' -o ${WORKSPACE}/tconv_coverage.info

genhtml --prefix /jenkins/workspace/TCONVENGINE-INSTRUMENTED-BUILD/TCONV/Main --title "TCONV Engine Coverage Analysis" --output-directory ${WORKSPACE}/lcov --num-spaces 3 ${WORKSPACE}/tps_coverage.info
```

Any help or assistance would be much appreciated, thanks in advance everyone

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39842139/783510

Answer (score 0):

It might help to add two backslashes before * in the remove list.
E.g. instead of

```
'Src/GeneralSubSystems/GA/Utils/*'
```

use

```
'Src/GeneralSubSystems/GA/Utils/\\*'
```

Comment: This would also exclude `Src/GeneralSubSystems/GA/Iterators` I want to include this specific package

Comment: Can't you enumerate all but Iterators in your removal list?